# Program prints forever when I run it. Error with array?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, printf, scanf

GOAL:

Problem 1

The program should read in numbers from a ﬁle named ”prob1 input.dat” that has the following format:

(number_of_entries) (entry1) (entry2)...

This means that the ﬁrst line of the ﬁle contains the number of entries provided by the ﬁle. The following lines deﬁne the entries where each line contains one entry. In our case, each entry will be a positive integer. The program should read in all entries and store them in an array. Then the program should check for each value in the array if it is a prime number or not and print out the result to a ﬁle named ”prob1 output.dat”. This ﬁle should have as many lines as numbers provided by the ﬁle ”prob1 input.dat”. In each line of the output ﬁle the program should print the number and then ” is a prime number” or ” is not a prime number”.

**BTW, ALL of the numbers in the file are greater than 25**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fptr;
    char prob1_input[] = "prob1_input.dat";
    int terms,i;
    int x[]={};

    fptr = fopen(prob1_input, "r");

    if (fptr == NULL)
        printf("Error in opening file %s",prob1_input);

    terms = x[0];

    for(i=0;i<terms;i++)
    {
        fscanf(fptr,"%d",&x[i]);
        terms = x[0];

        for(i=1;x[i]!=2;i++)
        {
            if(x[i]%2 == 0 || x[i]%3 == 0 || x[i]%5 == 0 || x[i]%7 == 0)
            {
                printf("%d is not a prime number\n",x[i]);
                break;
            }
            else if (x[i] == 2 || x[i] == 3 || x[i] == 5 ||  x[i] == 7)
            {
                printf("%d is a prime number\n",x[i]);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%d is not a prime number\n",x[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then learn how to use the debugger (`gdb`). BTW you should test the result of `fscanf`.

Comment: What do you expect this `int x[]={};` to do?

Comment: I struggle to find the words for `int x[]={};`

Comment: using the same variable in the inner and outer loop is a very bad idea.

Comment: Which value might `terms` carry after this `terms = x[0];` assignment?

Comment: @ alk the first number in the array is 100 (because there are 100 numbers listed after than in the file). So terms = 100.

Comment: @alk I was getting an error message when I had just x[] and I couldn't put 100 in there because this program is supposed to work with another file as well:(

Comment: Ignoring the fact that `x` does not refer to any valid memory, reading out `x[0]` before having assigned anything to it does not make any sense.

Comment: @WhozCraig I was getting an error message when I had just x[] and I couldn't put 100 in there because this program is supposed to work with another file as well:(

Comment: @alk, but what else could I have done to fix it? I was trying to store numbers to an array, but i can't do that without first defining it. But i can't define it yet. This is confusing. Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Use a step by step approach for this (the example code assumes full C99 support):

1. Define a variable to hold the numbers of values to come.

   ```
   size_t terms = 0;
   ```
2. Read from the file the number of values to come into the variable you defined under 1.

   ```
   fscanf(fptr, "%zu", &terms);
   ```
3. To hold the rest of the values to be read define an array with the number of elements as read under 2.

   ```
   x[1 + terms];
   x[0] = terms;
   ```
4. Read the number of values as read under 2. into the array defined under 3.

Comment: you cannot initialize a VLA.